# Regression in a loop but get "Error in coef(summary(fit))[2, 4] : subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, loops, regression, glm

When running the following code on a high dimensional dataset I get the error message

> Error in coef(summary(fit))[2, 4] : subscript out of bounds

The vector `beta` which the p-values of the logistic regression models are saved to has length 19481. If I loop through the different independent variables of the regression model up to 100 times I do not get this error.

Could anyone give me hint why my code does not run smoothly?

```
beta = rep(0, 19481)
for (i in 25:19505) {
  fit = glm(mdr.mdr ~ an.mdr[,i], family=binomial)
  beta[i-24] = coef(summary(fit))[2,4]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error comes when you try to extract `[2,4]` element of the coefficient table, that is, the p-value of the slope, I am sure you have `NA` estimate for the slope.

This means that for some `i`, your model is rank-deficient and there is no information to estimate the slope.

Note that, `coef(summary(fit))` will drop `NA` estimate, so in this situation your coefficient table only has one row instead of two rows (which explains the "out-of-bound" error). See [Coefficient table does not have NA rows in rank-deficient fit; how to insert them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40844853/4891738)

I suggest the following:

```
beta = rep(NA, 19481)
for (i in 25:19505) {
  fit = glm(mdr.mdr ~ an.mdr[,i], family = binomial)
  slope <- coef(fit)[2]
  if (!is.na(slope)) beta[i-24] = coef(summary(fit))[2,4]
  }
```

Another potential failure of this loop is "no complete cases", that is, `sum(complete.cases(mdr.mdr, an.mdr[, i]))` gives you 0. If this does happen, you might want:

```
beta = rep(NA, 19481)
for (i in 25:19505) {
  if (sum(complete.cases(mdr.mdr, an.mdr[, i])) > 0) {
    fit = glm(mdr.mdr ~ an.mdr[,i], family = binomial)
    slope <- coef(fit)[2]
    if (!is.na(slope)) beta[i-24] = coef(summary(fit))[2,4]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint.

Comment: Maybe from **R 3.5.0** we can just use `complete = TRUE` in `coef()`, but I haven't tested this as I am still on R 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Run the loop, and when it stops, type `i` into the console and press enter. This will tell you which loop iteration the loop failed at. Then inspect `an.mdr[,i]` for anything unexpected

Try this:

```
  beta = rep(0, 19481) 
  for (i in 25:19505) {
      fit = glm(mdr.mdr ~ an.mdr[,i], family=binomial) 
      if (is.na(coef(summary(fit))[2,4]) { beta[i-24] = NA }
      if (!is.na(coef(summary(fit))[2,4]) { beta[i-24] = coef(summary(fit))[2,4] }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint.